# Avoid text to push a div placement in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a text that will dynamically change length and when the length increase, it pushes the div to the right for it further to the right. What I want is to make sure the text length is not affecting the div on the right, not pushing it. The text start out with one char and will not be longer than two char.

In the picture below I tried to illustrate the problem first, and how I want it to look second.

[image]

```
#hjertePic {
position: relative;
margin-top: 29%;
margin-right: 26%;
float: right;
margin-left: 25%;
}

#heartCount {
position: relative;
float: left;
margin-top: 5%;
margin-left: 20%;
margin-right: 5%;
font-size: 100px;
color: white;
text-align: center;
}
```

heartCount is the text and hjertePic is the div I don´t want to move. Appreciate all the help I can get. :)

Comment: Make an ordered list out of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to use `display: inline-block` and a fixed width for the `div` containing number:

```css
.row .number, .row .text {
  display: inline-block;
}

.row .number {
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="number">1</div>
  <div class="text">DIV</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="number">2</div>
  <div class="text">DIV</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="number">13</div>
  <div class="text">DIV</div>
</div>
```